# how to create a runner class / run the spec flows through command line - C#?

Tags: c#, nunit, specflow, nunit-console

Can someone help in knowing how to create a runner class in C# to run all the specflows/features like we have a runner class in java?

Or is there any other way that I can run all the features through commandline ?

FYI, In the existing project's app.config i have -> unittestprovider name = "NUnit"

Answer (score 1):

SpecFlow generates test classes for SpecFlow+Runner, NUnit, MSTest, XUnit and MbUnit.
Everyone has it's own console runner which executes in the standard configuration all tests in an assembly.

Please have a look at the documentation of your used unit test runner.